# The well-defined temperature and 0D Ising model (Ref. Shankar)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, ising-model, partition-function

I’m reading Shankar’s book *Quantum field theory and condensed matter*. On page 17, these two bold sentences seem to contradict each other:

> **The system in contact with the heat bath and described by Z need not be large. It could even be a single atom in a gas.** The fluctuations of the average energy relative to the average need not be small in general. However, for large systems a certain simplification arises.
>
> Consider a very large system. Suppose we group all states of energy E (and hence the same Boltzmann weight) and write $Z$ as a sum over energies rather than states; we obtain
>   $$Z=\sum_E e^{-\beta E}\Omega(E)$$
>   where $\Omega$ is the number of states of energy $E$. For a system with $N$ degrees of freedom, $\Omega(E)$ grows very fast in $N$ (as $E^N$) while $e^{-\beta E}$ falls expotentially. The product then has a very sharp maximum at some $E^*$.The maximum of $$e^{−βE}\Omega(E) = e^{−(βE−ln\Omega(E))}$$
>   is the minimum of $βE−ln\Omega(E)$, which occurs when its $E$-derivative vanishes:
>   $$β = \frac{dln\Omega(E)}{dE}|_{E^∗}$$
>   which is the familiar result that in the most probable state the temperatures of the two parts in thermal contact, the reservoir and the system, are equal. (**This assumes the system is large enough to have a well-defined temperature. For example, it cannot contain just ten molecules.** But then the preceding arguments would not apply anyway.)
>
> We may write
>   $$Z = Ae^{−β(E^∗−kT ln\Omega(E^∗))},$$
>   where $A$ is some prefactor which measures the width of the peak and is typically some power of $N$. If we take the logarithm of both sides we obtain (upon dropping $lnA$ compared to the ln of the exponential),
>   $$ln Z = −β F = β (E^∗ − kT ln\Omega(E^∗ )) ≡ β (E∗ − S(E^∗ )T ),$$
>   where the entropy of the system is
>   $$S=kln\Omega(E^∗)$$.
>   In the limit $N → ∞$, the maximum at $E^∗$ is so sharp that the system has essentially that one
>   energy which we may identify also with the mean $⟨E⟩ = U$

- How should I understand those two bold sentences?

Chapter 2 of this book discusses Ising model in $d=0$, which has just two spin.
On page 20, It evaluates the partition function for this case.
$$E(s)=-Js_1s_2-B(s_1+s_2)$$
$$Z=\sum_{s_1,s_2}e^{\beta J s_1s_2+\beta B(s_1+s_2)}$$

- How is the temperature $T$ well-defined in this case?

Comment: "On page 17, these two sentences seem to contradict each other"... - perhaps for context it would be worth quote here the text of the page in full, highlighting two, in your opinion, conflicting sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed pretty poorly written. What he means seems to be the following:

- only a large system has a well defined temperature;
- since he wants to state the equality of the temperatures of the reservoir and of the system, he needs the system to be large;
- in any case, his argument that the energy concentrates on its most probable value only works for large systems (he is letting $N$ become very large).

On the other hand, he also says that

- the partition function can be used for small systems (even a single molecule);

This is fine, since the reservoir is macroscopic and therefore has a well-defined temperature. Note that, here, he is not saying that the small system has a well defined temperature, so there is no contradiction.

(That being said, in my opinion, one can argue that a small system at equilibrium with a macroscopic reservoir at temperature $T$ is also at temperature $T$. Indeed making many observations on the small system (e.g., determining the empirical distribution of its energy) will allow you to determine the temperature of the reservoir. However, a small system that is isolated does not have a well defined temperature.)

Comment: It would be nice to define what a *well-defined* temperature means. In a sense, the temperature is always well defined, it's a derivative of 
$ln \Omega(E)$ by energy $E$.On my opinion the idea of temperature as a derivative arises when considering the thermal contact of two systems. In order for the energy distribution of the system to depend only on its own energy and *a single external parameter*, the energy $E$ and number of degrees of freedom $N$ of another system - the environment (thermostat) need to be infinite, so that $E/N=const=T$ which is this single external parameter

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist : Oh, I am not saying that you cannot give a mathematical definition of "temperature" for a small, isolated system. The issue is whether this definition is meaningful. Note that the definition of temperature as $\partial E/\partial S$ originates in thermodynamics, where all systems considered are macroscopic. Whether its extension to isolated microscopic systems still makes physical sense is not obvious (to me). Say, take a single (classical) particle in a box, isolated from the rest of the universe. I don't see how any notion of temperature will be useful in such a setting...

Comment: ...useless but well-defined :)

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist : Right, I see your point. Maybe I should indeed have written "meaningful" in my answer instead of "well-defined" :) .